# How to open rar file in linux?

Tags: rar

I have a file with `.rar` extension, ex: `foo.rar`

I want to extract content from that file, how do I extract it?

Answer (score 135):

You can install `unrar` - "Unarchiver for .rar files" or `unp` - "unpack (almost) everything with one command"

To `unrar` a file:

- `unrar x <myfile>`

To `unp` a file:

- `unp <myfile.rar>`

Since `unrar` is not open source, some distros might not have it in their package manager already. If it's not, try `unrar-free`.

Notice that `unrar x <myfile>` will preserve directory structure in archive, in difference with `unrar e <myfile>` which will flatten it

Comment: There is also a `rar` command. It is binary-only and a bit less easy to use, but can open some files that `unrar` cannot.

Comment: On my Linux Mint 18.2 installation, unrar appears to be already installed and available by default.

Comment: I needed to first install it by running `sudo apt install unrar`. This is the official version and it has license prohibing some usage (no compression, only decompression). So you can also use the free version instead: `sudo apt-get install unrar-free`.

Comment: **NON FREE** terminal command for "basic data interchange format" is not a good option.

Comment: This `unp` is really awesome!

Answer (score 77):

You can use [`unar`](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline). This is *not* related to the non-free `unrar`, it's free software.

Easy to use:

```
 unar file.rar
```

Comment: @vonbrand: availability depends on the specific GNU/Linux distribution. For example [unar](https://www.parabola.nu/packages/libre/x86_64/unar/) is available for Parabola GNU/Linux-libre. Anyway I didn't mention "unrar", and unar != unrar

Comment: There is also something called _`unrar-free`_.

Comment: If `rar` is not open source, so much that 7-Zip on OSS distributions will not ship with it, how did `unar` manage to include it?

Comment: @palswim, rar is simply a proprietary format and the rar tool is an implementation (which has a non-open license). unar is another implementation that *is* free. Fedora removed the non-free rar tool due to its license, not because of anything regarding the rar format itself

Comment: Hum.. functional problem in `unar` that `unrar` not have, a file of 49750384 bytes, *"Failed! (Attempted to read more data than was available)"*. Sorry, bad program.

Comment: this worked for me on raspberry pi

Comment: I tried `unrar` first but it created 82TB files instead of 500kb files.  `unar` worked great, no weird sparse file problems, so highly recommended.

Comment: When  unrar cannot create directory, try unar, it works fine.

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip  # debian based systems
sudo yum install p7zip      # CentOS based systems    
7zr x myfile.rar
```

On Windows I rely on 7zip for rar and every other archive file, and it works on Linux, too.

Answer (score 12):

You can get unar from fedora repo, it's open and licence-pure:

```
dnf install unar
unar file.rar
```

Comment: Not available. `unrar`  is *not* open source (it is forbidden to analyze the code to reverse engineer a compression program), so Fedora won't ship it.

Comment: su -c 'dnf install http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'

Comment: dnf install unrar

Comment: also you can use unar for fedora 23.  did the author of the question asked about feora or opensource sollution or about unix rar sollution? @vonbrand

Comment: To install on debian, use: sudo apt-get install unar

Answer (score 7):

For Linux Ubuntu and Mint

### Installation

```
sudo apt install unar
```

### Usage

```
unar file_name.rar
```

## More info

- Extract an archive to the current directory: `unar {{archive}}`
- Extract an archive to the specified directory: `unar -o {{path/to/directory}} {{archive}}`
- Force overwrite if files to be unpacked already exist: `unar -f {{archive}}`
- Force rename if files to be unpacked already exist: `unar -r {{archive}}`
- Force skip if files to be unpacked already exist: `unar -s {{archive}}`

Answer (score 6):

Note that `unrar` is *not* open source (the license to the available source forbids using it to reverse engineer the compression, which violates point 6 "No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor" of the [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd)), and thus will not be shipped by Fedora.

Go to [Rar Labs](http://rarlab.com), check out the source for [`unrar`](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.3.11.tar.gz) (be careful, the version might have changed!), build and install (you'll need g++ and make), preferably for your account only:

```
$ tar zxf unrarsrc-5.3.11.tar.gz
$ cd unrar
$ make DESTDIR=$HOME all
$ make DESTDIR=$HOME install-unrar
```

Add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH`, and you are all set.

Yes, there is a RPM offered. I would't touch it with the proverbial 10 feet pole, more often than not third parties have no clue on how to create a correct RPM (it isn't exactly rocket science, but there are lots of details that have to be just right, see e.g. [Fedora's guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines)). Besides, there *are* differences between Fedora versions, "one size fits all" can't cut it.

**Update:** There is a RPM for `unrar` version 6.0.5 in the [RPM Fusion](https://rpmfusion.org) repository for Fedora 34. The license is cited as "Freeware with further limitations".

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu and Fedora (and perhaps other distributions as well), you have a GUI solution, **Archive Manager**.  It provides extraction of such archive files as `.rar` files.

Comment: It is rare to see a least popular answer (which was showed at the very bottom before my up-vote), to provide a simplest solution! Thanks @MAChitgarha!  For future readers: it is likely that your distro does NOT link the `.rar` extension name to **Archive Manager**. With the hint of this answer, I open the **Archive Manager** manually, and then use it to open the `.rar` file. It works like a charm!

Comment: @RayLuo Really thanks for your comment! Personally, `.rar` is linked to be opened with Archive Manager in Nautilus (maybe this is the default on Gnome), and even there is an option in the menu here (Fedora Gnome). Maybe something is out-of-date there, or you're not on Gnome? By the way, I'm happy to provide a simple solution for you!

Comment: it sounds like it would work out-of-box on Gnome, as it should be. With lots of Desktop Environments in Linux world, I happen to be not on Gnome. Still thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Use RAR `rar e <filename>` it comes with most distros. Created by brother of Eugene Rosahal who is the developer of RAR files.

Comment: `rar` is not a inbuilt command

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Anyway unrar neither. In fact, there is no way to extract rar files with a inbuilt command.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have sudo rights, **7zip** solved the problem for me. You need conda/miniconda installed beforehand:

```
conda install conda-forge::p7zip
```

And then

```
7z x foo.rar
```

Comment: Really wanted this to work but conda says that it doesn't exist: `$ conda install -c conda-forge 7zip

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - 7zip

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a nearest available file manager, either Norton-like (`Midnight Commander`, `Double Commander`, `Tux Commander`, etc., whatever is present in your distribution) or window-based (as `Dolphin`). Most of them have enough intelligence to open all kinds of archives in a manner suitable for manual contents exploring, but, sometimes, they use external tools. For instance, my Kubuntu suggests `Ark` in such cases. They would need an external tool, as `unrar`, for accessing proprietary archive formats; if so, install the latter using a package manager.

If you want to extract the entire archive or a single specified file, `unrar e` extracts without full path, and `unrar x` also makes intermediate directories.

Comment: Since `unrar` is *not* open source, Fedora won't ship support for it in any form.

Comment: @vonbrand Ubuntu provides both unrar and unrar-free. If Fedora can't include the latter, it's not a license issue.

Comment: @vonbrand moreover, there is no word for Fedora from original author. Your approach to limit question to the only non-most-used distribution is destructive.

Comment: Fedora won't ship anything that isn't open source. Unrar has strings attached ("don't use it to reverse engineer RAR compression"), so definitely not open source, and it *is* a licence issue.

Comment: FYI: Nice try. But "Midnight Commander" errors out with a message "... urar: 1: ... not found". I guess it would still need the command line `urar` to exist beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `unrar` package. On Fedora, for eample, you can do so with:

```
sudo yum install unrar
```

Then, use it to extract the files:

```
unrar e filename.rar
```

Comment: Fedora 23 has no `unrar` package among its official packages. I got the source an installed it in my account.

Comment: This is completely misleading. There is no such package.